# from social.apps.django_app.views import NAMESPACE

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

I am doing a project using Python 3.6, Django 2.0.7, and these guys:

```
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.5.0
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==2.0.7
django-bootstrap3==7.0.1
django-braces==1.13.0
django-oauth-toolkit==1.2.0
django-rest-framework-social-oauth2==1.0.4
djangorestframework==3.8.2
gunicorn==19.6.0
idna==2.7
oauthlib==2.1.0
Pillow==5.1.0
psycopg2==2.7.1
PyJWT==1.6.4
python-social-auth==0.3.6
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2018.5
requests==2.19.1
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
six==1.11.0
social-auth-app-django==1.1.0
social-auth-core==1.7.0
urllib3==1.23
whitenoise==3.2.1
```

The is the error message I am getting:

```
from .oauth2_grants import SocialTokenGrant
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/myvirtualenv/foodtasker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework_social_oauth2/oauth2_grants.py", line 13, in <module>
    from social.apps.django_app.views import NAMESPACE

ImportError: cannot import name 'NAMESPACE'
```

The question is how I can fix the issue and where I can import NAMESPACE.

Answer (score 0):

Django OAuth Toolkit does not support Django 2.x yet. From [documentation](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> #### Requirements
>
> - Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6
> - Django 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11

You can downgrade your Django installation to 1.11 to be able to use Django OAuth Toolkit and django-rest-framework-social-oauth2.

Comment: what do you advice me to do

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can downgrade.

Comment: I downgraded Django to 1.8 with Python 3.6
and this what I get

  raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (Django 1.8 (/Users/user/Desktop/myvirtualenv/foodtasker/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('django>=2.0'), {'django-oauth-toolkit'})
(foodtasker) Air-Aszakal:foodtasker user$

Comment: Well, it looks like the 3rd party tools you have chosen can't agree on similar requirements. Unfortunately you have to choose one or the other.